# Short method to solve determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have to prove the following determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a&b-c&c+b\\a+c&b&c-a\\a-b&b+a&c
\end{vmatrix}=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

I tried to solve it by expanding it, but it's getting too long.

Comment: Did you expand it by cofactors?

Comment: @AnthonyP yes , by cofactors

Comment: You'll have to just do it, unfortunately. Without any symmetry in that matrix, you can't fast-forward the process.

Comment: Where did this determinant come from?

Comment: Expanding a $3\times 3$ determinant is not «too long». You simply have to adjust your idea of length, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I am new here so I don't know how to write determinants. So I solved this on my notebook. If any doubt please ask me.

[image: page 1]

Comment: learn. Tex please.